# Typeahead: Uncaught Error Missing source

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

I am getting this error in console everytime I try to run the following code

```
$('#autcomplete_search').typeahead({
  highlight: true
},
{
  name: 'apple_game',
  remote: "/search/autocomplete?keyword=make"
});
```

Comment: What do your javascript includes look like?

Answer (score 7):

> Typeahead: Uncaught Error Missing source

If fetching remote, **you need to specify the engine**. Here is an example from the docs

```
var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: '../data/films/post_1960.json',
  remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json'
});

bestPictures.initialize();

$('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'best-pictures',
  displayKey: 'value',
  source: bestPictures.ttAdapter()
});
```

in this example, `var bestPictures` is your engine

### [bloodhound documentation](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound)

Comment: For reference, [bloodhound docs here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#bloodhound)